# How can i fetch page data from graph with only pageid

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have a problem with graph api.
The call "https://graph.facebook.com/[pageID]" fails with the message

```
    {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

I need the full url of the facebook-page. Is there a way to get the url of a page from pageid only?

EDIT: Thank you for tips. The error was, that when the page is not public, that i cannot query infos via graph. Its also not working, when i (admin of page!) call the graph-url...

Comment: Every page has a unique id (page_id).

Comment: I meant if you could provide the page id, we could check right now if the pageid is valid or not

Comment: Thank you. I solved it. The problem was, that the page was not public.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at [Page Graph API Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) there is a example url to get information about the page, include the url of the page that you want. The example url request is :

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552

and the result is :

```
  {
       "about": "Grow your app with Facebook\nhttps://developers.facebook.com/ ",
       "company_overview": "Facebook Platform enables anyone to build social apps on Facebook, mobile, and the web.\n\n",
       "is_published": true,
       "talking_about_count": 34563,
       "username": "FacebookDevelopers",
       "website": "http://developers.facebook.com",
       "were_here_count": 0,
       "category": "Product/service",
       "id": "19292868552",
       "name": "Facebook Developers",
       "link": "http://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers",
       "likes": 1187896,
       "cover": {
          "cover_id": "10151298218353553",
          "source": "http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/377655_10151298218353553_500025775_n.png",
          "offset_y": 0,
          "offset_x": 0
       }
    }
```

I think in your problem you put the wrong page ID.